# ¿Como accedo al Id de un elemento de tipo Html a través de php?

Tags: php

Bueno lo que quiero realizar es la impresión de los datos que están en dos campos de tipo fecha ya que necesito hacer una comparación.

Aquí están mis elementos HTML

```
$html['labels']['fecha'] = "<label for'fecha_filter'>Fecha Inicio</label>";
    $html['inputs']['fecha'] = "<input id='fecha_filter' type='date' size='12' maxlength='10' class='date' />";

    $html['labels']['fechaFin'] = "<label for'fecha_filter_Fin'>Fecha Fin</label>";
    $html['inputs']['fechaFin'] = "<input id='fecha_filter_Fin' type='date' size='12' maxlength='10' class='date' />";
```

Aqui me gustaria hacer el echo

```
        case 'fecha':

            $sWhere .= "(fecha>= '" . format_date_to_mysql(getDecode($_POST['filter_' . $column])) . "' AND fecha<= '" . format_date_to_mysql(getDecode($_POST['filter_fechaFin'])) . "') ";
            echo $sWhere;
            break;
```

Solo que no se como obtener el valor del campo html.

Ya se que en javascript se puede lograr pero me gustaría si hay alguna forma nativa a través de php con el cual pueda saber el valor de mis objetos html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cuando envias datos en un formulario, el valor de los campos es accesible por medio del atributo `name`, tendrías que agregar dicho atributo a tus campos (no hay necesidad de eliminar el atributo id y ambos campos pueden tener el mismo valor):

```
$html['labels']['fecha'] = "<label for'fecha_filter'>Fecha Inicio</label>";
$html['inputs']['fecha'] = "<input id='fecha_filter' name='fecha_filter' type='date' size='12' maxlength='10' class='date' />";

$html['labels']['fechaFin'] = "<label for'fecha_filter_Fin'>Fecha Fin</label>";
$html['inputs']['fechaFin'] = "<input id='fecha_filter_Fin' name='fecha_filter_Fin' type='date' size='12' maxlength='10' class='date' />";
```

Al momento de recibir el formulario:

```
$sWhere .= "(fecha>= '" . format_date_to_mysql(getDecode($_POST['fecha_filter'])) . "' AND fecha<= '" . format_date_to_mysql(getDecode($_POST['filter_fecha_Fin'])) . "') ";
```